# Disk queue length very high in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have two Servers A and B with the same settings, but on Server A, the query runs in 6 minutes and on Server B the same query runs in 15 minutes.

what I noticed is that on Server B is that disk queue length very high.

[image]

While on Server A, the same query does not have a large number of disk queue length.

[image]

What could be different for the same query to run in less time on Server A.

Could it be some problems with the Discs?

Thanks.

Comment: Find info about the query in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`on both servers. Especially take your attention at logical and physical reads and their difference.

Answer (score 0):

Disc queue is an indication that you have saturated the bandwidth to that disc. It indicates that you might have

- slow disk
- slow connection to a disk (or vhd)
- contention

(or any combination of these)

Look at where those discs are, how they are connected, and what is on them. Troubleshooting techniques depend on whether this is a VM (with VHD) or physical hardware.

I usually have the most success by asking my SAN admin (or VM admin) to issue me a drive (letter) "pinned to a spindle" (and not shared), and "scaling-out" (move my busy(est) DB to the new storage), but again, it depends on your equipment/situation.